# RXJS: is there a short equivalent of .pipe(take(1)).toPromise()?

Tags: rxjs, observable

Does Rxjs provide a more compact function equivalent to this call?

```
someObservable.pipe(take(1)).toPromise()
```

Comment: Looking through the docs I don't think there's anything particularly more compact than this. You could extract this into it's own function though:


`const resolveFirst = o => o.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();`

Comment: thx. I've had the same idea but then i'd have to create a generic function and manually add a type when calling.

Comment: I don't think there is.

Comment: you can also say `first()` instead of `take(1)`. but yeah , last/firstValueFrom() is the answer here

Answer (score 1):

`toPromise()` is actually deprecated now (at least in RxJs 7.x). You can use `firstValueFrom()`, which will return a Promise.

In your case you could write:

```js
@import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

export class example {
    async myFunction<T>(someObservable$: Observable<T>): Promise<T> {
        return await firstValueFrom(someObservable$);
    }
}
```

or use it with `.then()`, e.g.

```js
@import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

export class example {
    myFunction<T>(someObservable$: Observable<T>): Promise<T> {
        return firstValueFrom(someObservable$).then((value) => {
            return value;
        });
    }
}
```

See here: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom#firstvaluefrom